# How can I make Express support utf8mb4 charset?

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever I send a POST request to my Express server with an emoji in it the server crashes. It does not even hit the routes. I suspect this is a middleware issue. It appears that emoji's are not well documented in Express. How can I make Express support utf8mb4 charset?

Comment: ive never tried, but the first thing I would do is put a simple `app.use(function(req, res, next){ console.log('Got here'); next() });`. and move it around your middleware chain. This way you can at least identify what middleware is breaking it. Also, are you providing an charset/encoding hint in the content-type header?

Comment: I trouble shooted it in the way you suggested and concluded that the following line is causing the issue:  "app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));"

Comment: if you need json bodies, you will have to find or create a new middleware function that handles the strings correctly. You could try the json at http://jsonlint.com and you could also try searching and opening a github issue for the body parser repo